# Get Excel Cell by row NUMBER and column LETTER

Tags: vb.net, excel, interop

In VB.NET, using Interop.Excel, I need to access a cell based on a row number and column letter.  I tried my luck with...

```
pages.title = DirectCast(wksht.Cells(rows, "D"), Excel.Range).Value
```

Since the parameters took type object, I figured maybe this would work, but got no luck.  I also thought of enumerating each letter to a number, but the columns in the spreadsheet aren't as normal.  Meaning, they're not

A B C D E F G

They're actually...

A B C D E T AZ

I don't know if this makes a difference in the numbering of the columns.  The question should be obvious, but just to reiterate, how can I get a cell based on a row number and column letter?

Comment: If your columns are numbered (lettered) sequentially, you likely have hidden columns.  I'd be very surprised if your column T wasn't column 20.  In Excel, you can test this by writing the formula `=COLUMN()` in the column you want to test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a single cell:

```
wksht.Range(colLetter + rows)
```

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168292%28v=office.11%29.aspx#excelobj_link19)

Answer (score 4):

Use the ASCII values of the characters as a "base" system

> "A" = 1 = ASCII value of A - ASCII value of A + 1
>
> "AA" = 27 = (ASCII value of A - ASCII value of A +1)* 26 + (ASCII value of A - ASCII value of A +1)
>
> "BA" = (ASCII value of B - ASCII value of A + 1) * 26 + (ASCII value of A - ASCII value of A + 1)

etc., multiplying by 26 to the power of the (digit -1)

```
Function GetIndex(ByVal str As String) As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        str = str.ToUpper()
        GetIndex = 0
        For i = str.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
            GetIndex = GetIndex + (26 ^ (str.Length - i - 1)) * (Asc(str(i)) - Asc("A") + 1)
        Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Dim oWorksheet as Worksheet : Set oWorksheet = ActiveSheet

Dim iRow As Integer : iRow = 10
Dim strColumn as String : strColumn = "AZ"

Dim oCell as Range
Set oCell = oWorksheet.Cells(iRow, 1).Range(strColumn & "1")
```

`oWorksheet.Cells(iRow, 1)` gives you the first cell on the desired row, and `.Range(strColumn & "1")` gives you a horizontal offset from there based on the column letter(s).

---

**EDIT**: See Lance Roberts' answer for a much simpler solution.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the second part will give me the cell in the specified column?

Comment: Yes. It will be evaluated as .Range("AZ1"), which will be evaluated relative to the current cell (first cell in row 10). The "1" part means same row, while the "AZ" part means column "AZ". Since the current cell is in column A, this is the actual column AZ.

Comment: Aaargh. I've over-complicated this. Lance Roberts' answer is much better.

Comment: Lol, gotcha.  Good explanation though.